# Access denied mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, ssh, tcp

I'm having this strange error, spent the last hour on this and I'm still not sure to understand.

Yersterday, I could connect to mysql without any problem may that be from a remote source or locally.

Today, using mysqlworkbench, the tcp/ip works where as yersterday both standard tcp/ip and tcp/ip over ssh was working.

When I'm logged through ssh

- `mysql -u user -p -h localhost` works
- `mysql -u user -p -h mydomain.com` works
- `mysql -u user -p -h mydomain.com(actual ip)` works
- `mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1` do not work

mysql user config: `'user'@'%'`

my.cnf config: `bind-adress: mydomain.com (the actual ip)`

```
 #/etc/hosts
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       ubuntu
```

Also, interesting enough, even If I input localhost as MYSQL hostname for mysqlworkbench, the connection still can't be made.

EDIT 1:

I added `user@127.0.0.1` to `user,host` and the connection at `127.0.0.1` still can't be made.

EDIT 2:

Commenting `#bind-address: mydomain.com (the actual ip)` fixed the problem but this seems like a lazy fix, I would like to keep my IP for the actual address.

Comment: Check if your hosts file points localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I only use /etc/hosts and it seems like its pointing to the right place

Comment: No, commenting out bind-address is both the only, and the right way to allow access via multiple IP addresses. An IP address is system abstraction only tangentially relevant to system architecture (locations can be important which may be dependant on sub-nets).